# Can't enter non wordpress sub directory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a non WP directory in web root (same location WP is installed). I've tried the solutions at several of the other posts on this web site but I cannot get it to work!

I know this has to do with `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` so here is the `.htaccess` file in webroot

```
# BEGIN REMOVE SLUG CUSTOM POST TYPE RULES
RewriteRule ^location/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^event/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^event-recurring/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^store_page/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^safecss/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^team/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^clients/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^testimonials/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^jobs/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^faqs/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^slide/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
# END REMOVE SLUG CUSTOM POST TYPE RULES

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN wtwp_cache
# END wtwp_cache

# BEGIN wtwp_security
# END wtwp_security
```

All I want to do is to be able to view my index.php file that resides inside of /webroot/de-admin/. Currently and everything else I have tried still results in a 404 not found. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is this htaccess file? In document root?

Comment: @JonLin yes, web root, document root

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to just add an exclusion to the word press rules? For example:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^de-admin/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, unrelated but you have two of these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

And they'll never match because URI's that are passed through rules in an htaccess file has the leading slash stripped off. So you need to remove it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I just tried adding the line: `RewriteRule ^de-admin/ - [L]` and still no luck..dang 404! I didn't make this .htaccess file, I am working on this site for a friend. Good catch though, the second one is probably unnecessary

Comment: I've also tried adding a htaccess file inside of `de-admin` with `RewriteEngine Off` and still no success

Comment: you know what, I have a feeling this htaccess isn't really doing much. I just deleted it and the whole site still functions correctly, ugh I really dislike wordpress

Comment: @Ronnie You'd actually want to use `RewriteEngine On` in the case of adding htaccess to your `de-admin` directory. Turning it on for that directory means any rules in the parent directory are superceded.

Comment: something weird is going on with this server. I deleted some files from web root and I am able to access them over the web still. I am basically accessing files that aren't there anymore. I need to talk to my friend to see what is going on with this server. I turned RewriteEngine to On in that sub dir and still nothing. Thanks for the help so far